# Distinguish between optional and mandatory parameter

Tags: c#, optional-parameters

I have 2 overloads

```
void SomeMethod(SomeType parameter1, bool optionalParameter = true){} //1st overload
```

and

```
void SomeMethod(SomeType parameter1, bool parameter2, bool optionalParameter = true){} //2nd overload
```

How do I avoid ambiguity when calling second overload and omitting optional parameter? The compiler always chooses 1st overload instead. 
I see two ways:

1) switch parameter1 and parameter2 places:

```
void SomeMethod(bool parameter2, SomeType parameter1, bool optionalParameter = true){}
```

2) explicitly provide default value when using 2nd overload:

```
SomeMethod(parameter1, parameter2, true);
```

Comment: Different method names, or make all parameters mandatory.

Comment: Choose the option you like best: 1: Don't use optional parameters. 2: use named parameters, 3: change the order of the parameters. 4: choose different method names, 5: change the type of the parameters

Comment: The book clean code may help you here.  If you ever find yourself in this situation it's more times than not a design problem and you have to take a step back and think about WHY you're doing it the way you are.

Answer (score 6):

You can call it like that:

```
SomeMethod(parameter1, parameter2: parameter2);
```

As mentioned in the comments, that's the case of using named parameters. On a second look, this implementation doesn't make much sense. It looks like that either  you don't need the first method, either you don't need to have the extra parameter marked as optional on the 2nd method.

Comment: you're right. I'm working on eliminating the usage of the 1st overload. But while I'm in progress of replacing and testing, this strange behavior comes up. And thus the question.